# Adding Exception in htaccess RedirectMatch

Tags: .htaccess

I need to exclude the link /en/create/news to this rule

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[A-Za-z]{2}/([A-Za-z0-9,_.-]+)/news$ http://example.com/news/$1/news
```

I Tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[A-Za-z]{2}/([A-Za-z0-9,_.-]+!(create))/news$ http://example.com/news/$1/news
```

Did not work. 
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/create/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/([a-z0-9,_.-]+)/news$ http://example.com/news/$1/news [NC,R=301,L]
```

Or if you try to exclude `/create/` for all languages:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/create/ [NC]
```

Comment: The OP should check if mod_rewrite is loaded. `RedirectMatch` is from mod_alias I think.

Comment: Thanks Croises. Worked. Thanks for the help.